# Error with C# in html working with models

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a repository and now i want to use a foreach to add multiple items to the page but its giving me a error. My objective is: when there is no items in the page it will show a message but if the page have items will show a different message and the items. The code is the following:

**Controller:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Treino1.Models;

namespace Treino1.Controllers
{
    public class DespesasController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Despesa> despesas = RepositorioDespesas.Despesas;
            return View(despesas);
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult NovaDespesa()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult NovaDespesa(Despesa despesa)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                RepositorioDespesas.AddDespesa(despesa);
                return View("DespesaConfirmada", despesa);
            }
                return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Treino1.Models
{
    public static class RepositorioDespesas
    {
        private static List<Despesa> despesas = new List<Despesa>();

        public static List<Despesa> Despesas
        {
            get { return despesas; }
        }

        public static void AddDespesa (Despesa newDespesa)
        {
            despesas.Add (newDespesa);
        }



    }
}



@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Despesa Confirmada";
}

@model List<Treino1.Models.Despesa>


@if (Model.Count== 0)
{
    <h1>Sem Despesas...</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1>Despesas!</h1>
    @foreach (Treino1.Models.Despesa d in Model)
    {
        <div class="card bg-secondary border-dark">
            <div class="card-body">
                <b>Nome da Despesa: </b> @d.NomeDespesa
                <b>Quantidade: </b> @d.Quantidade
                <b>Valor: </b> @d.Valor
                <b>Categoria: </b> @d.Categoria
                <b>Pago? </b>
                @if (d.Pago)
            {
             @:Sim
         }else
            {
              @:Não
            }

        </div>
    </div>
    
}

}

<div>
    <a asp-action="NovaDespesa">Nova Despesa</a>
</div>
```

I think the error is something about the Model.Count==0 but i dont know how to solve.

The error is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data model in the `DespesaConfirmada` strongly typed view is defined as `@model List<Treino1.Models.Despesa>`, but when it rendered from the `public IActionResult NovaDespesa(Despesa despesa)` action method the single `Treino1.Models.Despesa` object is passed. Try to use like below:

```cs
public IActionResult NovaDespesa(Despesa despesa)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        RepositorioDespesas.AddDespesa(despesa);

        // Obtain corresponded records from the repository and pass to the view. 
        return View("DespesaConfirmada", RepositorioDespesas.Despesas());
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The error doesnt appear anymore but now when i add another item with the form the other disappear

Comment: @Crej00: The code in the answer is updated to obtain correct list of objects from the repository and pass the updated list to the view: `return View("DespesaConfirmada", RepositorioDespesas.Despesas()`. Did you try the latest updated code? Do you still have a problem with this code?